# Form Recognizer is not returning "keyValuePairs" array in JSON output using pre-built model

Tags: azure-form-recognizer

I am having issue with form recognizer pre-build model JSON output. It is not giving me the `keyValuePairs` array results. I have watched alot of videos where they are getting this array in the JSON output but in my case it only returns  `"readResults"` array rather that `"keyValuePairs"`. I have taken a screenshot of `keyValuePairs` array from a video. Please have a look at:

[image]

And here is the output of my form recognizer API call results:

[image]

My URL sample is : `https://myapp.com/formrecognizer/v2.1/prebuilt/invoice/analyze?includeTextDetails=true`

Is there any kind of additional parameter needed to be passed in the URL to get this `"keyValueParis"` array ? Like for `readResults` I am passing the parameter `includeTextDetails=true`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON output should have an additional section documrResults which includes the key value pairs. The readResult of the JSON output is all the text in the document.

Comment: Hi @Neta. Thanks for your reply. Yes the results JSON has a documentResults section. But the reason I asked for the keyValuePairs section is due to some missing information which is not defined in the form recognizer pre-defined keys. For instance: In most of the cases the Purchase Order on the invoice is labeled with a different key-word "Reference" and hence form Recognizer cannot identify that as a Purchase Order. That's the time where we can build our own logic from the "keyValuePairs" section to look for "Reference" keyword and grab the value. But that section is missing

Comment: @Jennifer I have the same issue still. My "keyValuePairs" show in development but they are not present in production. Any help would be great.

Comment: @dfeva which Form Recognizer API version are you having issues with?

Comment: @ChaZ I'm using 2023-07-31 (3.1 GA). I believe I need to pass a parm when sending my request but I can't find any info on how or what that value to pass is.

Answer (score 0):

You shared your url as *https://myapp.com/formrecognizer/v2.1/prebuilt/invoice/analyze?includeTextDetails=true*

To get the key value pairs for invoices you need to call the v3 API. More information [here][1]

The general document model (key value pairs) was introduced in the v3 API and is not supported in prior API verisons.
[1]: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-2022-08-31/operations/AnalyzeDocument